# Discord.py | Слэш команды

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Моя проблема заключается в том что когда я хочу использовать слэш команду то ответ на неё появляется не сразу. Только после 2-х, 3-х раз использовании данной команды. Сперва появляется ошибка, а дальше все работает нормально. Я бы хотел узнать с чем связанна данная проблема, и можно её как-либо решить. Чтоб сразу появлялся ожидаемый ответ от команды, а не ошибка.

[image]

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="c:", intents=discord.Intents.all())
slash = SlashCommand(Bot, sync_commands=True)

@slash.slash(description="Проверка бота")
async def ping(ctx):
    ping = Bot.ws.latency
    emb = discord.Embed(description="Ща сек...", colour=discord.Color.orange())
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    emb = discord.Embed(description=f'Pong! `{ping * 1000:.0f}ms` :ping_pong:', colour=discord.Color.orange())
    await msg.edit(embed=emb)
    print(f'[Logs] На данный момент пинг == {ping * 1000:.0f}ms | ping')

Bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После обновления кода надо подождать какое-то время, так как срабатывает рейт лимит, а для тестов обычно есть параметр `guild_ids`. Нужна ещё синхронизация.